# How to create a django application which requires a specific module to run?

Tags: django, django-apps

I have an application that requires the user to have a certain directory structure much like django does with templatetags and what I would like to know is how do I import an application named foo from a django project at runtime?
Furthermore if the application exists how do I import a specific module of application foo?

Comment: Does your app exactly have django's directory structure or is it really just "much like it django". Do you want Django to use this directory (use the models/templatetags)? Simply add your app to INSTALLED_APPS. Afterwards you can import via "from my_app import my_module"

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @Torsten: My app doesn't have the directory structure. It only knows that the users' project will have an application named foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question requires a few clarifying details. At the moment it seems as simple as putting the application (do you mean a django application?) on your pythonpath (e.g. inside the project directory):

```
try:
    import foo
except ImportError:
    pass # application mustn't be on pythonpath
else:
    from foo import specific_module
    # do stuff
```

Depending on your requirements, this code could be in a view, or even your project's `__init__.py` if you want it to happen quite early. Improvements to django's start-up process are coming soon -- keep an eye out for `startup.py` features.

If you need to import modules with dynamic names, you might want to look into [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)

You also have an helper method within django that is called django.utils.importlib.import_module (which uses [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__))

Comment: How does django do that? Do they use __import__ as well?

Comment: Yes, though specifically it uses a wrapper in `django.utils.importlib.import_module` (which uses `__import__`)

Comment: Than that should be your answer.

Comment: @the_drow heh :) you're the one who asked the question. He is pretty right and explanative with his answer

Comment: @tamizhgeek That's why I am accepting it. However, the django way is what I was looking for.